# redirect output of command to a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, redirect

I am trying to redirect the output of the following command to a variable $bei

```
awk '/Total number of/ && /multidriven/' ../reports/synthesis /hdl.check_design.rpt | grep -o '[0-9]' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

this command is working correctly if execute directly, and I am trying to redirect it into a variable to be used later.

I've tried 2 ways to do it:

```
bei= `awk '/Total number of/ && /multidriven/' ../reports/synthesis/hdl.check_design.rpt | grep -o '[0-9]' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` 

bei= $(awk '/Total number of/ && /multidriven/' ../reports/synthesis/hdl.check_design.rpt | grep -o '[0-9]' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}')
```

But they both don't work and I receive "command not found" error. Does anyone have any idea about this and could you please help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: do not put space between `bei` and `$(awk.....`

Comment: yeah! that's it! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Reason for failure seem to be extra space between `bei` and `$(awk.....)` .

Example :

```
sh-4.1$ x =$(date)  #With space 
sh: x: command not found
sh-4.1$ x=$(date)   #Without space
sh-4.1$ echo $x
Thu Sep 8 06:41:07 EDT 2016
sh-4.1$
```